# Issue dockerizing uppy-server

Tags: node.js, docker-compose, tus

I tried to build the image with my configuration for docker. I successfully build the image either with "docker build ." within the cloned directory or with "docker-compose up".

I run a container with the flag of --env-file providing all needed environment variables and this also runs successfully with no issues. 
I also that uppy server is up n running on Port 3020. Unfortunately, when I proceed to the client index.html file I tried to upload the files to a specific directory that is configured and I get error 404 ... Error of uploading the files.

That's the index.html script for hitting the endpoint on uppy-server

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  const uppy = Uppy.Core({ autoProceed: true })
  uppy.use(Uppy.Dashboard, { target: '#drag-drop-area', inline: true, height: 450 })
  uppy.use(Uppy.Tus, { endpoint: 'http://localhost:3020/' })

</script>
```

This is the **docker config file** config.docker when I bundle a container I add --env-file config.docker for setting the ENV variables

```
# Rename this file to env.sh, it will be kept out of Git.
# So suitable for adding secret keys and such
NODE_ENV="${NODE_ENV:-development}"
DEPLOY_ENV="${DEPLOY_ENV:-production}"
DEBUG="frey:*"

FREY_DOMAIN="localost:3020"
# FREY_ENCRYPTION_SECRET="***"
UPPYSERVER_PORT=3020
UPPY_ENDPOINT="localhost"
# for whitelisting multiple clients
UPPY_ENDPOINTS=""
# inform uppy client about the server host name
# UPPYSERVER_REDIS_URL=""
# UPPYSERVER_DATADIR="/mnt/uppy-server-data"
UPPYSERVER_DOMAIN="localhost"
UPPYSERVER_SELF_ENDPOINT="${UPPYSERVER_DOMAIN}"
# valid server hostnames for oauth handling
UPPYSERVER_DOMAINS="localhost:3020,playground.test/public/uppy/,playground.test,http://localhost:3020/,http://0.0.0.0:3020/"
UPPYSERVER_PATH=""
UPPYSERVER_IMPLICIT_PATH=""
UPPYSERVER_SECRET="mysecret"
UPPYSERVER_PROTOCOL="http"
# single oauth redirect handler for multiple server instances
UPPYSERVER_OAUTH_DOMAIN=""
UPPYSERVER_DROPBOX_KEY="***"
UPPYSERVER_DROPBOX_SECRET="***"
UPPYSERVER_GOOGLE_KEY="*****"
UPPYSERVER_GOOGLE_SECRET="*****"
UPPYSERVER_INSTAGRAM_KEY="***"
UPPYSERVER_INSTAGRAM_SECRET="***"
UPPYSERVER_AWS_KEY="***"
UPPYSERVER_AWS_SECRET="***"
UPPYSERVER_AWS_BUCKET="***"
UPPYSERVER_AWS_ENDPOINT="https://s3.{region}.amazonaws.com"
UPPYSERVER_AWS_REGION="***"
UPPYSERVER_UPLOAD_URLS="http://localhost:3020/,https://localhost:3020/"
```